# Visual Studio Code as mergetool for perforce

Tags: visual-studio-code, perforce

Using `VS Code` as a `difftool` for Perforce, you can write in the P4 Preference dialog.

```
Location: Path to exe
Arguments: -n -d %1 %2
```

But what do you write to use `VS Code` as a mergetool,
P4 says it must include `%1 %2 and %r`?

Comment: What is wrong with P4Merge as diff and merge tool?

Comment: Nothing wrong, I just prefer VS Code more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick google to see if VSCode has a merge option, and it looks like it does not: 
 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37350

Your best option is going to be to do a command line resolve, allow Perforce to do the merge to produce a file with conflict markers already inserted, and then use VSCode as an editor.

```
C:\Perforce\test\merge>p4 sync foo.txt
//stream/main/merge/foo.txt#2 - is opened and not being changed
... //stream/main/merge/foo.txt - must resolve #2 before submitting

C:\Perforce\test\merge>p4 set P4EDITOR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe -n -w"

C:\Perforce\test\merge>p4 resolve
c:\Perforce\test\merge\foo.txt - merging //stream/main/merge/foo.txt#2
Diff chunks: 0 yours + 0 theirs + 0 both + 1 conflicting
Accept(a) Edit(e) Diff(d) Merge (m) Skip(s) Help(?) e: e
```

[image: VSCode merge screenshot]

Alternatively you could make a fakey VSCode merge tool by using `p4 merge3` (or for that matter `diff3` or any other merge utility that can write its output in a plain text format) and then opening the result in VSCode:

```
C:\Perforce\test\merge>cat vsmerge.bat
@p4 merge3 %1 %2 %3 > %4
@code -n -w %4

C:\Perforce\test\merge>p4 set P4MERGE=vsmerge.bat

C:\Perforce\test\merge>p4 resolve
c:\Perforce\test\merge\foo.txt - merging //stream/main/merge/foo.txt#2
Diff chunks: 0 yours + 0 theirs + 0 both + 1 conflicting
Accept(a) Edit(e) Diff(d) Merge (m) Skip(s) Help(?) e: m
```

This produces basically the same result as using VSCode as the editor and picking "e", but may be preferable if you only want to use VSCode for merging and don't want it popping up when you edit forms.

Answer (score 1):

The latest vscode is supporting merge tool now.

usage: `--merge %1 %2 %b %r --new-window --wait`

VS Code will open a new window and run merge tool.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I am only missing this step:

p4 set P4MERGE= ???